# SQL Server call function in the IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sapb1

I have a function that returns set of `itemcodes`. The result is correct but when I call it in stored procedure it doesn't show anything:

```
declare   @itemgroupCode int
set       @itemgroupCode=118
declare   @todate datetime
set       @todate='15.april.15'

declare   @Group nvarchar(Max)
set       @Group=(SELECT [dbo].[CurrProduction] (118,'15.APRIL.2015'))
select @Group

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 
o.ItemCode as [Item],tm.ItemName as Dscription,o.Warehouse as Wr,obtn.LotNumber, 
itl1.quantity as qty ,tm.U_Reusb,@Group as Grp

from OINM o inner join OITL on OITL.DocType = o .TransType and OITL.DocNum = o.BASE_REF  and OITL.DocLine= o .DocLineNum and OITL .LocCode = o.Warehouse and o .ItemCode = OITL.ItemCode
inner join ITL1 on ITL1.LogEntry = OITL.LogEntry and ITL1.ItemCode=OITL.ItemCode
inner join OITM  tm on tm.ItemCode = ITL1.ItemCode 
inner join OITB on tm .ItmsGrpCod = OITB .ItmsGrpCod
INNER JOIN OWHS AS OH   ON o.Warehouse=OH.WhsCode
inner join OBTN on OBTN.SysNumber = ITL1.SysNumber and OBTN.ItemCode = ITL1.ItemCode and tm.ManBtchNum = 'Y'
 WHERE  --tm.ItmsGrpCod=108 and
  tm.ItemCode in (@Group) 
 and o.DocDate<=@todate ) as s  
PIVOT 
(
 SUM(qty)
 FOR Wr IN (
 [DIS],[G&I],[GD-001],[GD-002],[GD-003],[GD-004],
 [GD-005],[GD-006],[GD-007],[GD-008],[GD-009],[GD-010],
 [GD-011],[GD-012],[GD-013],[GD-014],[GD-015],[GD-016],[GD-017],[GD-018],
 [GD-019],[GD-020],[GD-021],[GD-022],[GD-023],[GD-024],[GD-025],[GD-026],
 [GD-027],[GD-028],[GD-029],[GD-030],[GD-031],[GD-032],[GD-033],[GD-034],[GD-035],
[KHI AB],[KHI MM],[Loan],[LUB],[Main],[PCG - M1],[PCG - M2],
[PHS],[PMG],[PRO],[REJ],[REP],[REP-V],[Selling],[SKP]
)
)AS PVT
```

The function returns following when I paste in `IN CLAUSE` it gives me the correct result, but when I pass in the result of the function call, it doesn't show anything

Function returns:

```
'FYCT-00063','FYCM-00016','FYCM-00064','FYCF-00018','FYCM-00021','FYOG-00016','FYCM-00004','FYCM-00031','FYCM-00042' function code is following.

**

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CurrProduction]
(
@unit varchar(10), @date datetime
)
RETURNS Varchar(Max) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar varchar(Max)
  SELECT DISTINCT @ResultVar='''' + REPLACE(STUFF((
   SELECT    ',',+CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
   FROM OWOR
   where OWOR.PostDate=@date AND OWOR.U_Unit=CASE
                                 when @unit=108 then 'Unit No1'
                                 when @unit=118 then 'Unit No 2'
                                 when @unit=119 then 'Unit No 3' END
    AND OWOR.Status!='C'
    FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE)
   .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' '),',',''',''')+''''                    

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @RESULTVAR
END
```

**

Comment: What is the type of function? What does this function returns?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri This is uderdefined function and it return varchar

Comment: it should be inline table valued function and return resultset, then you can do like  `where itemcode in(select * from [dbo].[CurrProduction] (118,'15.APRIL.2015')))`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri IT GIVE ME NOW ERROR AT icorrect Syntax Near AS Keyword

Comment: Edit question with latest script and also show your function

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i also post the function code.

Comment: Did you read my answer? It should return table not varchar

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I READ BUT SEE THE FUNCTION THAT I POSTED CAN THIS RETURN  LIKE THIS

Comment: See my answer for edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you want the function should be an `Inline Table Valued` function. Then you can simply call it in `IN`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ttinline(id int)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ttinline
VALUES  (1),(2),(3)

CREATE FUNCTION fnInline()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
return SELECT * FROM dbo.ttinline
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.ttinline WHERE id IN(SELECT * FROM dbo.fnInline())
```

Output:

```
id
1
2
3
```

**EDIT:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CurrProduction]
(
@unit varchar(10), @date datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
   SELECT DISTINCT CAST(OWOR.ItemCode AS VARCHAR(10)) AS CODE
   FROM OWOR
   where OWOR.PostDate=@date AND OWOR.U_Unit=CASE
                                 when @unit=108 then 'Unit No1'
                                 when @unit=118 then 'Unit No 2'
                                 when @unit=119 then 'Unit No 3' END
    AND OWOR.Status!='C'
GO


DECLARE @itemgroupCode INT
SET @itemgroupCode = 118
DECLARE @todate DATETIME
SET @todate = '15.april.15'

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    o.ItemCode AS [Item] ,
                    tm.ItemName AS Dscription ,
                    o.Warehouse AS Wr ,
                    obtn.LotNumber ,
                    itl1.quantity AS qty ,
                    tm.U_Reusb 
          FROM      OINM o
                    INNER JOIN OITL ON OITL.DocType = o.TransType
                                       AND OITL.DocNum = o.BASE_REF
                                       AND OITL.DocLine = o.DocLineNum
                                       AND OITL.LocCode = o.Warehouse
                                       AND o.ItemCode = OITL.ItemCode
                    INNER JOIN ITL1 ON ITL1.LogEntry = OITL.LogEntry
                                       AND ITL1.ItemCode = OITL.ItemCode
                    INNER JOIN OITM tm ON tm.ItemCode = ITL1.ItemCode
                    INNER JOIN OITB ON tm.ItmsGrpCod = OITB.ItmsGrpCod
                    INNER JOIN OWHS AS OH ON o.Warehouse = OH.WhsCode
                    INNER JOIN OBTN ON OBTN.SysNumber = ITL1.SysNumber
                                       AND OBTN.ItemCode = ITL1.ItemCode
                                       AND tm.ManBtchNum = 'Y'
          WHERE     --tm.ItmsGrpCod=108 and
                    tm.ItemCode IN ( SELECT CODE FROM [dbo].[CurrProduction](118, '15.APRIL.2015') )
                    AND o.DocDate <= @todate
        ) AS s PIVOT 
( SUM(qty) FOR Wr IN ( [DIS], [G&I], [GD-001], [GD-002], [GD-003], [GD-004],
                       [GD-005], [GD-006], [GD-007], [GD-008], [GD-009],
                       [GD-010], [GD-011], [GD-012], [GD-013], [GD-014],
                       [GD-015], [GD-016], [GD-017], [GD-018], [GD-019],
                       [GD-020], [GD-021], [GD-022], [GD-023], [GD-024],
                       [GD-025], [GD-026], [GD-027], [GD-028], [GD-029],
                       [GD-030], [GD-031], [GD-032], [GD-033], [GD-034],
                       [GD-035], [KHI AB], [KHI MM], [Loan], [LUB], [Main],
                       [PCG - M1], [PCG - M2], [PHS], [PMG], [PRO], [REJ],
                       [REP], [REP-V], [Selling], [SKP] ) )AS PVT
```